# Assigning a substitute value in case of nil

Tags: ruby

I have a few variables:

```
name
age
address
phone
social_security
email
weight
```

And an array called `personal_details` with each of these values in positions 0-6.

So I assign values like this:

```
name = personal_details[0]
address = personal_details[1]
phone = personal_details[2]
social_security = personal_details[3]
email = personal_details[4]
weight = personal_details[5]
```

In some cases, however, the data on the right hand side does not exist.

**What's a more elegant way to handle this than writing something like this for each element in the array?**

```
if !personal_detail[0].nil?
 name = personal_details[0]
else
 name = ""
end
if !personal_detail[1].nil?
 address = personal_details[1]
else
 address = ""
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this since a `nil` value returns false and `||` will only evaluate the right-hand side if the left-hand side is false:

```
name = personal_details[0] || ''
```

Answer (score 2):

```
name = personal_details[0] || ""
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This is incorrect, see discussion below.

There is a built-in way to do this with [Array#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000274):

```
personal_details = ['Joe User', nil, '12 Main Street']

name    = personal_details.fetch(0, '')
age     = personal_details.fetch(1, '')
address = personal_details.fetch(2, '')
```

The other solutions will work fine based on the example you provided.  If one of the values on the right-hand side is set to `false`, the `||` approach will return the empty string instead of the value.

Comment: Are you sure that `fetch` works the way you think? From the docs: Tries to return the element at position index. If the index *lies outside the array*...returns default. A quick experiment with `irb` suggests that it doesn't return the default value if there's *any* item at the index you request (even `nil`). So it doesn't work for the OP's case, since he's not wondering about items beyond the end of his array.

Comment: You're right - I had tested out the code and saw nothing displayed and just assumed that it was returning the empty string.  Instead, it was returning nil which looked the same at first glance.  I'll edit the answer.