# Value or "default"

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assigning a substitute value in case of nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736408/assigning-a-substitute-value-in-case-of-nil)

In Lua I use

```
x = value or "default_if_value_is_nil"
```

(as a shortcut for `if value ~= nil then x = value end`)

Can I do something similar in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = value || "default_if_value_is_nil_or_false"
```

Note the "or false" here, though the same probably holds in Lua too.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. What's the difference between || and or in Ruby then?

Comment: Precedence. `or` has a very low precedence, so `a = b or c` is interpreted as `(a = b) or c`.

Comment: @Bożena The precedence is different, see [Using `and` & `or` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) and [Difference between `or` and `||` in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby).

Comment: Many thanks! But this precedence is unusual, in most languages assignment has the lowest precedence.

Comment: Like so many things in Ruby, it's borrowed from Perl: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do the same thing in ruby

```
x = nil_value || "default"
```

Note that this will also work for any other "falsey" value as well

```
x = false_value || "default"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = value or "default_if_value_is_nil"
```

is a perfectly legal Ruby statement, but be aware that `or` has one of the lowest priority in operators precedence. Also know that in a Ruby boolean operation everything is true except false and nil, thus this Ruby statement will also answer the default even if value is not nil but false.

```
puts '>>> assignment = has a higher priority than or <<<'
value = 'y'
x = value or "default_if_value_is_nil"
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"

value = false
x = value or "default_if_value_is_nil"
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"

value = nil
x = value or "default_if_value_is_nil"
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"

puts '>>> put parenthesis around or expression to have a higher priority than = <<<'
value = 'y'
x = (value or "default_if_value_is_nil")
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"

value = false
x = (value or "default_if_value_is_nil")
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"

value = nil
x = (value or "default_if_value_is_nil")
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"

puts '>>> || has a higher priority than = <<<'
value = 'y'
x = value || "default_if_value_is_nil"
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"

value = false
x = value || "default_if_value_is_nil"
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"

value = nil
x = value || "default_if_value_is_nil"
print 'value=', value.inspect, ', x=', x.inspect, "\n"
```

Output:

```
>>> assignment = has a higher priority than or <<<
value="y", x="y"
value=false, x=false
value=nil, x=nil
>>> put parenthesis around or expression to have a higher priority than = <<<
value="y", x="y"
value=false, x="default_if_value_is_nil"
value=nil, x="default_if_value_is_nil"
>>> || has a higher priority than = <<<
value="y", x="y"
value=false, x="default_if_value_is_nil"
value=nil, x="default_if_value_is_nil"
```